# To visit Paris on return from NL

Tags: schengen, paris, amsterdam

Will visit Amsterdam for 45 days from July first week to mid August. This is an official visit, company sponsored. I've already been to Italy a few times and Amsterdam once before. My plan is to visit Paris on one of the weekends. Seems I can do so with the NL Schengen visa I've got. But my question is.....

Usually my tickets are booked on Lufthansa - India to Frankfurt to Ams and same way back.

If I can persuade the travel manager to book the return through Paris instead of Germany with a transit gap of 10 hours or more , then can I utilize this time to visit Paris (just Eiffel tower trip and Louvre museum) ?

This way I can save some Euros to spend in Amsterdam.

Answer (score 3):

There'd be no *formal* (that is, passport or visa related) problems with this plan.

Whether a 10-hour layover is enough to get value for your (or your employer's) money out of Paris is something you will have to decide for yourself. Depending on how risk-averse you are, a significant part of those 10 hours could be eaten up by getting from and to the airport, waiting in security and passport control lines and so forth.

Then waiting in line for the Eiffel Tower can itself take hours on a bad day, unless you book a skip-the-lines tour in advance ...

Comment: Thanks.My question was more about permission - 'Am I allowed ?' to visit the city when I'm on a transit with 2 boarding cards in hand. Though I must cross immigration (getting out of Schengen Europe) only after the city visit

Comment: @Chakravarthy: No problems of that kind. There's nobody who checks that passengers _leaving_ the airport _don't_ have an onward boarding card -- and returning from your city trip, presenting that onward boarding card will get you into the line for security just fine.